# Azure Media Services clip live archive

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I have a live stream on Azure Media Service that I want to create a dynamic filter on to only show a small section of that stream. Imagine that we have a stream going on for 24 hours and but the content that current user cares about is only 1 minute long. So we want to create a dynamic filter on this stream that only shows this specific minute.

When I read this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-dynamic-manifest-overview#creating-subclips-views-from-a-live-archive

It says: "With Dynamic Manifest, **you can create filters using start/end times** and create virtual views over the top of your live archive.".

However, when I check another page for the filters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/operations/presentationtimerange

It says: "EndTimestamp: Applies to VoD. For the Live presentation, it is **silently ignored** and applied when the presentation ends and the stream becomes VoD."

Is it not possible to use dynamic filters (presentationeTimeRange) to create a small video clip for a live stream? Do the live stream needs to end before it's possible?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It was possible with V3 of the api. I had previously only used V2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do to get manifest containing specific 1 minute of presentation,

1. A LiveEvent has been going on for, say, 48 hours
2. The LiveOutput has a 24 hour DVR window
3. So if current time is 10AM Tuesday, the DVR window contains video+audio data in the range (10:00:01 AM Monday - 10:00AM Tuesday)
4. There is a segment of interest that is one minute in duration, say 6:00PM – 6:01 PM on Monday
   a.  Content is still in the DVR window
5. You want to create a dynamic filter to return just the (6:00PM Monday – 6:01PM Monday) portion
   a.  If so, then set StartTimestamp and Endtimestamp to correct timestamp on video timeline along with flag forceEnd=true

Note: Assuming live ingest keeps going, this filtered manifest request will return,

a. Empty manifest, if requested before 6:00PM Monday

b. Live manifest, if requested between 6:00PM Monday – 6:01PM Monday

c. VOD manifest, if requested after 6:01PM Monday till all the fragments in that 1 minute are still in DVRWindow

d. http Error, if any one of the fragments present in the filtered manifest (6:00PM – 6:01PM on Monday) goes out of DVR window.